# How can I edit this function to run ONLY when input fields are completed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I have a function which captures the data from two date input fields.

I have a click listener on an img, which fires the function. I want to edit my code so it only fires the function if both date fields are completely filled in (mm-dd-yyyy).

If one or both are not filled in, I want to return a string "Please fill in date field, and click again".

I also have two text input fields (for names) with no functionality. Similarly, I would like the name input fields to require at least one letter in each, otherwise it returns a similar string, like "Please enter a name for each field and click again!".

```js
    var sumButton = document.querySelector(".sumNumbers");
    sumButton.addEventListener("click", getSum);

    function getSum() {
    // Place the id's of the input and output elements into respective arrays
    let inputs = ['dateInput1','dateInput2'];
    let outputs = ['result1','result2'];

    // Loop over the items in the inputs array
    // This will cause you to loop as many times as there are input elements
    inputs.forEach(function(input, index){

    // Instead of hard-coding the element id, you get the element reference
    // from the .forEach callback function argument.
    const inputValue = document.getElementById(input).value;
    var sum = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < inputValue.length; i++) {
        const num = parseInt(inputValue.charAt(i));
        if (!isNaN(num)) {
            sum += num;
      }
    }

    const total = (sum - 1) % 9 + 1;

    // And here, you reference the right output element, by using the corresponding index from the inputs array.
    document.getElementById(outputs[index]).textContent = "Your number is: " + total;

    });
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="cell-1" id="centerElement">
            <div id="cell-1-nest-l"></div>
            <div id="cell-2-nest-l"></div>
            <div id="cell-3-nest-l"></div>
            <div id="cell-4-nest-l"><h3>your name</h3></div>
            <div id="cell-5-nest-l"></div>
            <div id="cell-6-nest-l"><input type="text" class="nameStyle1" 
    id="nameInput1" ></div>
        </div>

        <div class="cell-2" id="centerElement" >
            <img 
    src="file:///Users/Nineborn/Downloads/My%20Post%20(5).png" alt="" class="sumNumbers">
        </div>

        <div class="cell-3" id="centerElement" >
            <div id="cell-1-nest"></div>
            <div id="cell-2-nest"></div>
            <div id="cell-3-nest"><h3>their name</h3></div>
            <div id="cell-4-nest"></div>
            <div id="cell-5-nest"><input type="text" class="nameStyle1" 
    id="nameInput2"></div>
            <div id="cell-6-nest"></div>                              
        </div>

        <div class="cell-4" id="result1">
            <input type="date" class="dateStyle1 reset" id="dateInput1"></div>             
            <div class="cell-5"><input type="reset"></div>
            <div class="cell-6" id="result2"> 
            <input type="date" class="dateStyle2" id="dateInput2" placeholder="Their 
    Bday"></div>
            <div class="cell-7"></div>
            <div class="cell-8"></div>
            <div class="cell-9"></div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That function doesn't do anything that seems related to looking at a date string.

Comment: not sure i understand, Im trying to require the input field to be fully completed before the function can be run. If it isnt completed, I want it to return a string (text?) to alert the user that the fields need to be completed.

Comment: What you are talking about is validation, and is something that has been solved many times over. I suggest doing some research into the topic -- you'll find many libraries ready to run that will help, including some built into the browser.

Comment: ok thanks, i was having trouble researching it, i didn't know how to articulate the problem into a google search

Comment: first you have to validate the input fields then run your function i see no validation here

Comment: so if i stick an if statement preceding the function, with a regex, and then an else, which simply prints the string (please re-enter...etc) ...is that a good example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should call a function to validate your inputs and if it passes, then you can call your function to do as you wish. You must have a submit inside a form. From reading your question, you mentionned using an image as the submit. You can use this `<input type="image" src="/Button1.jpg" border="0" alt="Submit" />` instead of the button in my demo.

**Here is a demo :**

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["date"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Date must be filled out");
    return false;
  } else {
    yourfunction();
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  Date: <input type="date" name="date">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```